# How to query MYSQL table to get counts of column occurrence overall and within past year?

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql

I am using MySQL and want to create a query that will count how many times appointments happened per contact_id within the last year, last year,  and how many times the occurrence happened overall.

My appointment table has the following rows with sample data:

```
id | contact_id | appointment_date | status_id

1  |  1         |  2019-01-01      | Attended
2  |  1         |  2018-05-01      | Attended
3  |  2         |  2019-04-01      | Cancelled
4  |  2         |  2019-05-01      | No Show
5  |  1         |  2018-07-01      | Cancelled
6  |  1         |  2019-08-01      | Not Complete
```

So let's say I want to see how many times contact_id '1' had appointments, here how I'd want the result to look:

```
 Status       |  Total overall | Total this year | Total last year
 Attended     |  2             | 1               | 1
 Cancelled    |  1             | 0               | 1
 No Show      |  0             | 0               | 0
 Not Complete |  1             | 1               | 0
```

Is this query do-able with MYSQL?

I will be using it in an HTML/PHP/jQuery web application.  I am going to have a button that will generate this information once clicked.  Perhaps I should scrap the query idea and somehow manipulate it using some sort of jQuery table/data manipulation after a simple

'`SELECT * from appointments WHERE contact_id = 1'`?

Comment: `select status_id, count(status_id) AS "Total overall" from appointments where contact_id = '1' group by status_id ` Use something like this for a starter

Comment: Perfectly 'do-able', as demonstrated below, but consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to have it in a single query, you can try something like this:

```
SELECT
      status_id
    , COUNT(*) AS `Total overall`
    , SUM(IF(YEAR(appointment_date) = YEAR(CURDATE()), 1, 0)) AS `Total this year`
    , SUM(IF(YEAR(appointment_date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) - 1, 1, 0)) AS `Total last year`
FROM
    appointment
WHERE
    contact_id = 1
GROUP BY
    status_id
```

=>

```
status_id   total   total_this_year total_last_year
Attended    2   1   1
Cancelled   1   0   1
Not Complete    1   1   0
```

The above query will not return information for 'No Show'. If you really need all statuses, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT
      s.status_id
    , IFNULL(a.total, 0) AS `Total overall`
    , IFNULL(a.total_this_year, 0) AS `Total this year`
    , IFNULL(a.total_last_year, 0) AS `Total last year`
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            DISTINCT status_id
        FROM
            appointment
    ) AS s
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
              status_id
            , COUNT(*) AS `total`
            , SUM(IF(YEAR(appointment_date) = YEAR(CURDATE()), 1, 0)) AS `total_this_year`
            , SUM(IF(YEAR(appointment_date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) - 1, 1, 0)) AS `total_last_year`
        FROM
            appointment
        WHERE
            contact_id = 1
        GROUP BY
            status_id
    ) AS `a` ON (
        a.status_id = s.status_id
    )
```

=>

```
status_id   Total overall   Total this year Total last year
Attended    2   1   1
Cancelled   1   0   1
Not Complete    1   1   0
No Show 0   0   0
```

P.S. I do not like the years calculations I used in the query, however, keeping it as is here for simplicity.
In real life, I'd use range comparison `appointment_date BETWEEN CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), '-01-01') AND CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), '-12-31')` instead of `YEAR(appointment_date) = YEAR(CURDATE())`.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try this out. Yes, though,  I would like one query. Can you tell me about range comparison or provide me with more info why you don't like YEAR calculation?  I'll search around in the meantime.  Thanks.

Comment: If you have such comparison in WHERE, the server will not be able to use index and it will do the function calculations for every record that might be costly if you have many records.